# Can I find out what application is using a mirror driver?

Tags: windows, drivers

According to Windows, my machine can no longer display the Aero interface as an application is using a "mirror driver". I can't think of any software I've installed recently that would need to mirror my display, so is there a way for me to find out what application is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find this information in the `Device Manager`. It should be located in the `Display Adapters` section.

Commonly this problem is associated with remote administration software such as LogMeIn, UltraVNC, TightVNC, Radmin and RemotePC.

Comment: Ah ha, "LogMeIn Mirror Driver". Very strange, I've had LMI installed for months and months. Maybe they've pushed out an update... Thanks!